# How to get a virtual and real reserves from UniSwap V3 pair?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, defi, uniswapv3, math

I need help with math of UniSwap V3 virtual and real reserves. Need to find the true reserves of a pair (value of token0 = value of token1). Example:

Let's say we have this DAI/WETH pair: 0x60594a405d53811d3BC4766596EFD80fd545A270
balance of DAI was - 2591437269710515203595384 & balance of WETH was - 2838497576725882781612
As we can see here, reserve's of tokens in this pool disbalanced
DAI value in pool - 2,594,028.706980225 $ - 43 %
WETH value in pool - 3,461,888.414526421 $ - 57 %

If I'am not mistaken, because of concentrated liquidity we have a different virtual reserve's in every "concentrated" zone. Also, those virtual reserve's should be balanced (50/50 - value) by x*y=k. Does anyone know how to find those virtual and/or real reserve's?

I've succesfully calculated a price of both token's:
token0Price= sqrtRatioX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192 = 2267580935849786082246943435 **2 / 2 **192 = 5.141923300629392e+54 / 6.277101735386681e+57 = 0.0008191556417896165

token1Price =  2 ** 192 / sqrtRatioX96 ** 2 = 6.277101735386681e+57 / 2267580935849786082246943435 **2 = 6.277101735386681e+57 / 5.141923300629392e+54 = 1220.7692274636495
And price's are fine.

Also, I've got:
Reserves token0
x = L / sqrt(P)
x = 776218541774739337116335 / sqrt(0.0008191556417896165)
x = 776218541774739337116335 / 0.02862089519
x = 2.7120694046143822e+25
x = 27120694046143822000000000

Reserves token1
y = L * sqrt(P)
Suppose that sqrt(P) is sqrt(token1Price) then:
y = 776218541774739337116335 * sqrt(1220.7692274636495)
y = 776218541774739337116335 * 34.9395081171
y = 2.7120694040982028e+25
y = 27120694040982028000000000

x = 27120694046143822000000000
y = 27120694040982028000000000

Yeah, it's look like 50/50, but not by it's token reserves value. I'm not sure, that's my math is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: The virtual reserves in terms of `x` and `y` are very rarely needed; liquidity is almost always what you want to calculate and use. Real reserves in a pool are complex to calculate because of the non-uniform liquidity. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71815432/2435820

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mjs file I created for the token balance of a V3 position, the math should be easily extractable

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import * as fs from 'fs';


    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('<path>/ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('<path>/V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('<path>/V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

    // V3 NFT manager abi
let NFT = fs.readFileSync('<path>/UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<API_Key>")

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";



async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}



const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));
const MIN_TICK = -887272;
const MAX_TICK = 887272;


function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}


async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh);
    
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    let sqrtPrice = sqrtPriceX96 / Q96;
    
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    else if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    else if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtPrice)/(sqrtPrice*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtPrice-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = (amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal)).toFixed(token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = (amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal)).toFixed(token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}




async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}


start(5)
```

Comment: Thank's al lot!) Will test!

Comment: yeah, no problem. feel free to ask questions, and I'm a uniswap friend in the uniswap discord